# Parsing a json file present in the desktop using angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

Im a new bie to Angular JS. I have .json file which is present in my desktop where i need to parse the json file and fetch the values from json.

I tried using $http.get("inputfile.json",function($scope,$http){
}

when i tried open my web page in firefox, it gives an error "not -well formed" error and it points to first line of json.

Can you please help me to fix the issue?

Comment: put your json in project folder and give a relative path to the json file.. and run your application on localhost, may be you can use http-server..

Comment: add your json here It looks like problem is in your json file not in json path

Comment: {
 "users": [{
  "title": "Java script is not workng",
  "postedon": "2 mins ago",
  "Noofanswers": 1,
  "Username": "tomnjerry",
  "Questionid": "1"
 }, {
  "title": "Eclipse configuration in windows",
  "postedon": "5 Days ago",
  "Noofanswers": 3,
  "Username": "rocks",
  "Questionid": "2"
 }]
}

Comment: form a json without using these brackets []